# If I delete/shut down a project from google cloud console, will the respective firebase project will also get deleted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I delete/shut down a project from google cloud console, will the respective firebase project will also get deleted?and it's firebase database, storage etc., will also get deleted?

Answer (score 2):

A Firebase project **is** a GCP project. You'll notice they have the same unique ID and show the same data.  When you use the Firebase console, it activates GCP services and provides an additional way to manage them.  If you delete the GCP project, you are also effectively deleting the Firebase project, since they are fundamentally the same thing.

You can easily test this for yourself by creating and deleting as many temporary projects as you want.  There should be no billing incurred for this.